Laravel Vue Update page prop of user data After axios post
I have a custom column inside by user's table called avail_balance.  When making a transaction, I want the available balance to update on the frontened WITHOUT having to reload the page.  So after an axios post, it will react properly and update the value.
Inside my AppLayout, towards the header section, I can view this value in the template with:
AppLayout.vue (main app layout)
<template>
   <div>
   {{ $page.props.auth.user.avail_balance }}
   </div>
</template>

Then inside one of my child components, it has a "submit transaction" axios call that post's the necessary data and updates the user's available balance in the backend database.
makeOrder.vue (child component)
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3';

const page = usePage();

function orderSubmit () {

     let data = ['300'];
   
    axios.post('/orders/store', {data}).then(res=>{
    page.props.auth.user.avail_balance.value = '300'; 


    }).catch(err => {
      if (err.response.status === 422) {        
        errors.value = err.response.data.errors;
        errors.message = err.response.data.errors.messages;     
       }

    })
    return;

}
</script>

I get an error that looks like:
 TypeError: Cannot create property 'value'
After I make the order submit and it returns successful, I would like the available balance prop value to be updated on the AppLayout template portion WITHOUT having to refresh the webpage.  The value updates correctly only if I manually refresh the page.
How can I go about this?  Do I need to assign the $page.props.auth.user.avail_balance to a vue ref and then update the vue ref directly inside the axios post response?
TIA!

you can put the $page.props.auth.user.avail_balance inside vue ref like: ref($page.props.auth.user.avail_balance) and update it from there ?

try router.reload() in then block . need to import router from inertia

Thanks!  You guys both helped me get it working properly.  router.reload is big, and now its time for me to see if I can partially reload that user variable only.

you can partially reload like router.reload({only:['auth']})

After reading the comments, I was able to get it working by:

creating a computed value for the available balance  (ref did not work but computed did).
 const availableBalance = computed(() => { return page.props.auth.user.avail_balance; });


then inside the axios post call, adding router.reload


